# Sub-queries filtering too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

My Sub-queries are filtering out too many results. It Should be filtering out the 12 ingredients used in the 3 recipes in the sub-queries. There are a total  79 Ingredients so the query should return 67 rows. Currently my query is returning 54.

I'm unsure why but if I change the second WHERE condition to an OR instead of AND I get 68 rows which is only one off what I'm expecting

Query I'm trying to create:

*(5) Find the IDs and names of all ingredients not used in Irish Stew,
Pollo Picoso, or Roast Beef. (2 columns, 67 rows)*

```
select distinct Recipes.RecipeID, Ingredients.IngredientName
from Recipes
inner join Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
inner join Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
where Ingredients.IngredientID NOT IN
    (select distinct Ingredients.IngredientID
    from Recipes
    join Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
    join Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
    where Recipes.RecipeTitle = 'Roast Beef')
and Ingredients.IngredientID NOT IN
    (select distinct Ingredients.IngredientID
    from Recipes
    join Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
    join Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
    where Recipes.RecipeTitle = 'Irish Stew')
and Ingredients.IngredientID NOT IN
    (select distinct Ingredients.IngredientID
    from Recipes
    join Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
    join Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
    where Recipes.RecipeTitle = 'Pollo Picoso');
```

Database Diagram:
[image]

[DB Fiddble I created](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba5decece2de32495488876cc0b86e52)

Comment: first off use `not exists`

Comment: *Find the IDs and names of all ingredients* why do you select `Recipes.RecipeID` if you need only ingredients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to only join when I'm interested in a joined result. This is not the case here. You only want to see ingredients matching some condition. That is `FROM ingredients WHERE ...`. Conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause. Thus you get a query that is easily understandable and hence well maintainable.

`DISTINCT` on the other hand is very often a sign for a poorly written query (just joining everything and then grabbing some means to get rid of what we unnecessarily produced ourselves). That can also be quite costly, because this creates a bigger intermediate result which must then be sorted to find the created duplicates.

I'd use `NOT IN` and `IN` to get all ingedrients that are **not in** the set of ingredients the recipe of which are **in** 'Roast Beef', 'Irish Stew', and 'Pollo Picoso'.

```
select ingredientid, ingredientname
from ingredients 
where ingredientid not in 
(
  select ingredientid
  from recipe_ingredients
  where recipeid in
  (
    select recipeid
    from recipes 
    where recipetitle in ('Roast Beef', 'Irish Stew', 'Pollo Picoso')
  )
)
order by ingredientid;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select distinct ri.IngredientID
from Recipe_Ingredients ri inner join Recipes r
on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
where r.RecipeTitle in ('Roast Beef', 'Irish Stew', 'Pollo Picoso')
```

returns the 12 ingredients that you want to exclude.
Only the tables `Recipe_Ingredients` and `Recipes` need to be joined.
Now left join `Ingredients` to that query and return only the unmatched rows:

```
select i.IngredientID, i.IngredientName
from Ingredients i
left join (
  select ri.IngredientID
  from Recipe_Ingredients ri inner join Recipes r
  on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
  where r.RecipeTitle in ('Roast Beef', 'Irish Stew', 'Pollo Picoso')
) t on t.IngredientID = i.IngredientID  
where t.IngredientID is null
```

You could also get the same results with `NOT IN`:

```
select IngredientID, IngredientName
from Ingredients 
where IngredientID not in (
  select ri.IngredientID
  from Recipe_Ingredients ri inner join Recipes r
  on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
  where r.RecipeTitle in ('Roast Beef', 'Irish Stew', 'Pollo Picoso')
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bc5e9418b6afa349fe44b9e932ca128).
Result is 67 rows of ingredients.

Comment: @Tomarik really? Will you use 3 nested INs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need -

```
select distinct R.RecipeID, I.IngredientName
from Recipes R
inner join Recipe_Ingredients RI on R.RecipeID = RI.RecipeID
inner join Ingredients I on RI.IngredientID = I.IngredientID
where R.RecipeTitle not in ('Roast Beef',  'Irish Stew',  'Pollo Picoso');
```

Let me know if this doesn't fulfill your requirement.